# Exception generated when trying to generate jmeter HTML reports

Tags: html, jenkins, jmeter, reporting

I am trying to generate html reports through the jmeter non gui commands.

HTML reports are not getting generate and also seeing the below error with regards to the same.

## COMMAND USED TO RUN:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_statisfied_threshold=1500  -n -t D:\jmeter\v1_images_scenario.jmx -l D:\jmeter\images.jtl -e -o D:\jmeter\Reports\
```

## ERROR MESSAGE:

> Error generating the report:
>   org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Cannot assign
>   "${jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold}" to property
>   "set_satisfied_threshold" (mapped as "setSatisfiedThreshold"), skip it
>   Facing same error after setting the threshold as well .

Tried searching more on this , but couldn't be able to resolve the issue. Would be great if some once could help me on this.Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your command, change it to look like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=1500 -n -t D:\jmeter\v1_images_scenario.jmx -l D:\jmeter\images.jtl -e -o D:\jmeter\Reports\
```

i.e. change `statisfied` to `satisfied`

Going forward check the following files:

- reportgenerator.properties
- user.properties
- jmeter.properties

For the following line:

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold=${jmeter.reportgenerator.apdex_satisfied_threshold}
```

and once found - delete or remove it, this way you will be able to generate the dashboard using default threshold of `500` if you don't override the property.

More information:

- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)

Answer (score 13):

Although the accepted answer resolved the OP's issue, I thought I would add an additional answer here as I ran in to this same behaviour and was unable to find a quick answer, thus wasting a lot of time searching, digging and the like.

In my scenario I had, mistakenly, changed from using `-q <properties file>` to `-p <properties file>`.  What I didn't realize (at the time) is `-q` defines an *additional* properties file to be read, whereas `-p` **overrides** the jmeter.properties file.  Thus when using `-p` I was missing properties that were required to correctly generate the dashboard.  Incidentally, the "Summariser" (logger that periodically writes statistics to stdout) also stopped working, so that was an additional side effect.  Interestingly my tests weren't failing, just the dashboard creation error and the missing Summariser.

Looking at the *official* documentation: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options this distinction is made, but other sites out there aren't so clear on that matter.  So there you go...

Comment: Using `-p` worked fine with JMeter version 5.4.1, for me. So the need to use `-q` instead, in version 5.5, seems to be an undocumented change, or a bug?